# CSS word-wrap and inline-block not work

Tags: css

I have long text without spaces (like URL) in a `<div>`.

```
<div>
  <span>veryverylongtextwithoutspaces</span>    
</div>
```

If I set `display:inline-block;`, then the word-wrap doesn't work!

If I set `display: block`, then word-wrap works as it should! But `div` gets 100% width.

I need size div of the contents. Thank you

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #DCF8C6;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #DCF8C6;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <span>veryverylongtextwithoutspaces</span> 
</div>

I want this, but not work "word-wrap":
<br>
<div class='inline'>
  <span>veryverylongtextwithoutspaces</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: without setting a `width` we have no way of knowing when to break the word.. perhaps with more context I can help?

Comment: It's not clear what the desired result would be. Why do you need wordwrap? Perhaps setting a max-width might be an option?

Comment: I've included your jsFiddle to be inline with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** define a width to the content's container. Additionally, I believe you'll want to use `word-break` instead of `word-wrap`

```css
p.keep {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

/* This will do what you want */
p.break {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p class="keep">ThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolong</p>
<p class="break">ThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolongThisiswaytoolong</p>
```